# Regular expression for ten digit number

Tags: javascript, regex, input

My program here is trying to have the user input in a text field, and if the user input is a 10-digit number(numbers with 0's at the beginning or any of that sort count) when they press the check button they will receive an alert saying what their number is, or otherwise they will receive an alert telling them to enter a proper number.

However, whenever I press the button, nothing changes. I believe that there is a problem inside my regular expression and the function, but I am not sure how to write a regular expression that searches for a particular pattern where there are 10 digits in the result of a form.

Here are the relevant bits of my code.

```
<form name = submitnumber">
  <input type = "text" size = "15" name = "inputnumber"></input>
  <button type = "button    " onclick = "checknumber()">Check</button>
</form>
<script type "text/javascript">
  function checknumber() {
    var tendigitnum = /^\d+${10}/; 
    var input_num = document.getElementByName("inputnumber")
    if (input_num.search(tendigitnum)) {
      window.alert("You entered: " + input_num);
    } else {
      window.alert("Please enter a valid 10 digit number!");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Open your browser console (usually F12) - your regex is not valid and should be logging an error (the first of a few).

Comment: There are several issues in your code, any one of which will cause failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex's syntax is wrong.

Make it

```
var tendigitnum = /^\d{10}$/;
```

and use it as

```
tendigitnum.test("2342343434"); //outputs true
```

Also, there is no such method as `getElementByName`, you need to use `getElementsByName` and returns multiple elements. Make it

```
var input_num = document.getElementsByName("inputnumber")[0].value;
```

Comment: also, when I press on the check button, the input just disappears and no alert is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I have, and when i switch the order of the alerts the program works!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the regex to a valid one

```
var tendigitnum = /^\d{10}$/;
```

and the right access to the element's value with

```
document.getElementsByName("inputnumber")[0].value
```

and you need to perform a match with

```
if (input_num.match(tendigitnum)) {
    //
}
```

```js
function checknumber() {
    var tendigitnum = /^\d{10}$/; 
    var input_num = document.getElementsByName("inputnumber")[0].value;
    if (input_num.match(tendigitnum)) {
        alert("You entered: " + input_num);
    } else {
        alert("Please enter a valid 10 digit number!");
    }
}
```

```html
<form name = submitnumber">
    <input type="text" size="15" name="inputnumber"></input>
    <button type="button" onclick="checknumber()">Check</button>
</form>
```